# Haskell writing >>= using >=> Monads

Tags: haskell, monads

```
(>=>) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> (a -> m c)

bind :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

-- how do you use `>=>` to write `bind`?

I am absolutely so confused, I understand how both of these works but I cant even get started.

I tried all the following alternatives:

```
bind1 a b = (b a)
bind2 a b = (a >=> b)
bind3 a b = (b >=> a)
bind4 a b = (a b)
```

but every single attempt raises an error. Where can i possibly start on this question?

Since `>>=` has 2 parameters, and `>=>` has 3, how can I use `>=>` to write `>>=` when there is 1 less parameter?

Comment: What did you think `|` was going to do?

Comment: @chepner It's just a weird delimiter: "these are the four things I tried, separated by `|`s".

Comment: Don't make up pseudosyntax; it just confuses the reader. Spell out the 4 attempts you made clearly.

Answer (score 4):

First I'd suggest renaming the type parameters so *the final result* matches:

```
(>=>) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> (a -> m c)
bind :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m c)               -> m c
```

Now we have a `b -> m c` in the first signature and `a -> m c` in the second; that suggests renaming also `a` to `b`:

```
(>=>) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> (a -> m c)
bind :: Monad m =>     m b     -> (b -> m c)       -> m c
```

That leaves the main difference as having an extra argument `a`. But we evidently don't need that, so we might as well specialize it to the information-less type `()` (or any other single-value type):

```
(>=>) :: Monad m => (() -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> (() -> m c)
bind :: Monad m =>         m b  -> (b -> m c) ->        m c
```

`() -> m x` is actually isomorphic to `m x` alone:

```
addDummyArg :: a -> (() -> a)
addDummyArg c () = c
rmDummyArg :: (() -> a) -> a
rmDummyArg f = f ()
```

And it's just a matter of using those conversion functions to adapt the functions to each other.

Answer (score 2):

> Since `>>=` has 2 parameters, and `>=>` has 3, how can I use `>=>` to write `>>=` when there is 1 less parameter?

Each function in Haskell has one parameter. You can interpret `>=>` , as a function that has as first parameter something of type `a -> m b` and the second something of `b -> m c`, the `a -> m c` is the "result" function.

What you here can do is manipulate the first parameter of `bind` into a function that accepts a parameter, and then provide that parameter, something like:

```
bind :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
bind ma f = (const ma >=> f) undefined
```

Here with `const ma`, we thus create a function that takes a parameter we do not care about, then we construct an `a -> m c` by using `>=>` and we call it with `undefined` (or some other value) to produce the `m c` value.